# parcelable is not working android

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I'm trying to send an ArrayList of custom objects to the next activity but its not working for me. I've been all day trying to implement Parcelable with no luck at all. I've done my research here on SO but i'm still getting an error: `Cannot convert Parceable[] to ArraList<Song>` This is my code for parceling my object:

```
// Parcelling part
    public Song(Parcel in){

        this._id = in.readInt();
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.path = in.readString();
        this.artistId = in.readInt();
        this.albumId = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents(){
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Song> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Song>() {

        public Song createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Song(in); 
        }

        public Song[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Song[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeInt(_id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(path);
        dest.writeInt(artistId);
        dest.writeInt(albumId);

    }
```

**In my first activity i just:**

```
ArrayList<Song> songs = db.selectAllSongs();
playerActivity.putParcelableArrayListExtra("songs", songs);
```

**And in my second activity i just:**

```
ArrayList<Song> songs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra("songs");
```

I don't know why im getting an error when i'm implementing Parceable. I need a little guiding. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*I hope this will help for you. In this way i am using parcellable values*

```
    public class Channel implements Serializable, Parcelable {

/**  */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4861597073026532544L;

private String cid;
private String uniqueID;
private String name;
private String logo;


/**
 * @return the cid
 */
public String getCid() {
    return cid;
}

/**
 * @param cid
 *            the cid to set
 */
public void setCid(String cid) {
    this.cid = cid;
}

/**
 * @return the uniqueID
 */
public String getUniqueID() {
    return uniqueID;
}

/**
 * @param uniqueID
 *            the uniqueID to set
 */
public void setUniqueID(String uniqueID) {
    this.uniqueID = uniqueID;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name
 *            the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the logo
 */
public String getLogo() {
    return logo;
}

/**
 * @param logo
 *            the logo to set
 */
public void setLogo(String logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}



public Channel(Parcel in) {
    super();
    readFromParcel(in);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Channel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Channel>() {
    public Channel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Channel(in);
    }

    public Channel[] newArray(int size) {

        return new Channel[size];
    }

};

public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    String[] result = new String[23];
    in.readStringArray(result);

    this.cid = result[0];
    this.uniqueID = result[1];
    this.name = result[2];
    this.logo = result[3];

}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { this.cid, this.uniqueID,
            this.name, this.logo});

}}
```

*And in Activity class*

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("channel",
                        (ArrayList<Channel>) channels);
```

*And in the second Activity screen get the bundle parcelable array like this*

```
Bundle getBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
List<Channel> channelsList = getBundle.getParcelableArrayList("channel");
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `Intent.getParcelableArrayExtra()` [(link)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayExtra%28java.lang.String%29) returns an array of parcelable objects.  You're assigning that to an ArrayList object, and the compiler is complaining because `ArrayList`s aren't arrays.

Try using `getParcelableArrayListExtra()` instead.

Comment: and where should i use getParcelableArrayListExtra() the compiler wouldnt know what or where im getting the parcelable arraylist from...

Comment: You can call that method on the Intent object.  Put the array list in the Intent as an extra with putParcelableArrayListExtra(), send the intent wherever you want, then retrieve the array list with getParcelableArrayListExtra().